# Artificial grounds to remove static electricity on a metal frame?

Tags: static-electricity

I am a vex robotics student. Our team has an issue where ports on our robot core stop working due to static electricity buildup on the metal frame around the motors. Is it possible to make an artificial ground to suck in static electricity on the metal frame with a capacitor or battery? (We can't do a ground to a house or anything cause the robot is controlled remotely)

Comment: No, not possible to do it that way. You need to figure out where the frame is getting its charge from and provide a conductive path between those two points. For example, if it's because of the wheels rubbing and skidding on a carpet then perhaps some kind of conductive brush to wipe the wheels that connects to wire that is dragged along the ground. Or just dragging a wire connected to the frame along the ground.

Comment: It might be possible to drag a conductor from your robot to the ground. Or, could you use metal wheels that are electrically connected to the frame of the robot?

Comment: One possible explanation for what is happening is that you have triboelectric effect at the interface between the wheels and the ground. I had this happen on a dynamometer for a skateboard. The charge buildup was between the dyno and the skateboard because of urethane skateboard wheels rolling on steel dyno wheels. We fixed it by adding a metal clip between the skateboard truck and the dynamometer. You might be able to drag a long metal spring finger on the ground, or use conductive wheels. By the way, automobile tires are conductive partly for this reason.

Comment: Thanks you all for your advice! Yeah vex field tiles are designed to be anti static so its seems like it's the lack of grounding from the chassis to the ground, or from the chassis to the wheels. (Also often times when I unplugged a port that stopped working, I would get a small static shock from the chassis which definantly shows the lack of ground there, the brain also has a lack of a direct ground on the chassis too, since its connected by rubber to the chassis for shock resistance) All of your answers really helped me to figure out the issue, again, thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use wire or a conductive paint such as [Aquadag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquadag) or window [defroster repair paint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HBGKWE) to connect parts so that static is "grounded" from the wheel to the chassis. The problem is that the ground of the *ports* is not connected to the ground of the *chassis*, not that it needs to be connected to an "earth ground".